# Writing my own piping function in C

Tags: c, shell, pipe, piping

I am trying to write my own function for piping in C. First, once I have already forked and am in the child, I check to detect where the pipe is input, as below. I am looping through my own StringArray I've created (sa), and copying the token before into char cmd1[64] (initialized previously) and the token after into char cmd2[64]. The int piping is given a value for the next step.

```
if(strcmp(sa[i], "|") == 0)
        {
            printf("got to the pipe\n"); 
            sa[i]=NULL; 
            strcpy(cmd1, sa[i-1]); 
            strcpy(cmd2, sa[i+1]); 
            piping=2; 
        }
```

Then, the program reaches this statement:

```
if (piping)
{
    if (pipe(fd) != 0){
        perror("Failed to create pipe"); 
    } 
    if ((cpPid = fork()) == -1){
        perror("Failed to fork"); 
    }
    if (cpPid == 0){
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(cmd1, sa);
        error("failed to exec command 1");  
    }
     else
    {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(cmd2, sa);
        error("failed to exec command 2");
    }
}
```

My program completely crashes and only gives out Unknown error 10275024. Can someone help me to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Without MCVE there is nothing to say.

Comment: I created the same thing for an homework, this helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948221/does-this-multiple-pipes-code-in-c-makes-sense

Comment: @EugeneSh. What is MCVE ?

Comment: It's a bit suspicious that you seem to be presenting the same argument array to both of the commands you are `exec`ing.

Comment: @PandaCool, MCVE is [mcve].

Comment: Also, if your `pipe()` or your `fork()` fails, you just print a diagnostic and attempt to continue with what you would do if they succeeded.  That seems unlikely to work.  If one of those functions fails, you need to abort.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this working example that should help you execute a pipeline using C.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef int Pipe[2];

/* exec_nth_command() and exec_pipe_command() are mutually recursive */
static void exec_pipe_command(int ncmds, char ***cmds, Pipe output);

static void err_vsyswarn(char const *fmt, va_list args) {
    int errnum = errno;
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, " (%d: %s)", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    putc('\n', stderr);
}

static void err_syswarn(char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    err_vsyswarn(fmt, args);;
}

static void err_sysexit(char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    err_vsyswarn(fmt, args);
    exit(1);
}

/* With the standard output plumbing sorted, execute Nth command */
static void exec_nth_command(int ncmds, char ***cmds) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    if (ncmds > 1) {
        pid_t pid;
        Pipe input;
        if (pipe(input) != 0)
            err_sysexit("Failed to create pipe");
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
            err_sysexit("Failed to fork");
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* Child */
            exec_pipe_command(ncmds - 1, cmds, input);
        }
        /* Fix standard input to read end of pipe */
        dup2(input[0], 0);
        close(input[0]);
        close(input[1]);
    }
    execvp(cmds[ncmds - 1][0], cmds[ncmds - 1]);
    err_sysexit("Failed to exec %s", cmds[ncmds - 1][0]);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}
/* exec_nth_command() and exec_pipe_command() are mutually recursive */
/* Given pipe, plumb it to standard output, then execute Nth command */
static void exec_pipe_command(int ncmds, char ***cmds, Pipe output) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    /* Fix stdout to write end of pipe */
    dup2(output[1], 1);
    close(output[0]);
    close(output[1]);
    exec_nth_command(ncmds, cmds);
}

/* Execute the N commands in the pipeline */
static void exec_pipeline(int ncmds, char ***cmds) {
    assert(ncmds >= 1);
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_syswarn("Failed to fork");
    if (pid != 0)
        return;
    exec_nth_command(ncmds, cmds);
}

/*  who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n */
static char *cmd0[] = {"who", 0};
static char *cmd1[] = {"awk", "{print $1}", 0};
static char *cmd2[] = {"sort", 0};
static char *cmd3[] = {"uniq", "-c", 0};
static char *cmd4[] = {"sort", "-n", 0};

static char **cmds[] = {cmd0, cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4};
static int ncmds = sizeof(cmds) / sizeof(cmds[0]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    exec_pipeline(ncmds, cmds);
    return (0);
}
```

The pipeline example in the code is

`who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

You can use any pipeline.

Test:

```
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/C/> 
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n 
      1 dac
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/C/> gcc main.c 
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/C/> ./a.out 
    1 dac
```