# How to manage multiple pipes

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a multiple pipe for my shell in C.

All I have is a pipe function that pipe `a | b` but not `a | b | c`.

```c
int   c[2];
int   returnv;
pid_t id;

pipe(c);
pid = fork()) == 0
if (pid)
{
  dup2(c[1], 0);
  close(p[1]);
  close(p[1]);
  execvp(array(0), array);
}

if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
  dup2(p[0], 1);
  close(p(0));
  close(p[0]);
  returnv = execvp(array[0], array);
}

close(p[1]);
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL);
return returnv;
```

And this is a second version:

```c
int i = 0;
 
while (i < x)
{
   pipe(c);
   if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
   {
       dup2(t[i], 1);
       if (i < 2)
       dup2(p[0], 1);
       close(p[1]);
       r = execvp(cmd[i][0], cmd[i]);
   }
   wait(NULL);
   close(p[0]);
   i += 1;
   t[i] = p[1];
```

How can I make this code manage multiple pipes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementation of multiple pipes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389033/implementation-of-multiple-pipes-in-c)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To perform multiples pipes you need to store all your commands somewhere.

That's why I used a tab of structure.

So first, you need a tab or something to store all your commands:

```c
int main()
{
  char *ls[] = {"ls", NULL};
  char *grep[] = {"grep", "pipe", NULL};
  char *wc[] = {"wc", NULL};
  char **cmd[] = {ls, grep, wc, NULL};

  loop_pipe(cmd);
  return (0);
}
```

Then the function will run through the tab and launch everything.

```c
void    loop_pipe(char ***cmd) 
{
  int   p[2];
  pid_t pid;
  int   fd_in = 0;

  while (*cmd != NULL)
    {
      pipe(p);
      if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        {
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      else if (pid == 0)
        {
          dup2(fd_in, 0); //change the input according to the old one 
          if (*(cmd + 1) != NULL)
            dup2(p[1], 1);
          close(p[0]);
          execvp((*cmd)[0], *cmd);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      else
        {
          wait(NULL);
          close(p[1]);
          fd_in = p[0]; //save the input for the next command
          cmd++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will give a working version of the two pipe model, and a hint for the three pipe model.

NOTE: If you do not include the proper header files, `dup2()` will be a nightmare.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int p[2];
int pid;
int r;

main()
{
    char *ls_args[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char *grep_args[] = {"grep", "pipe", NULL};

    pipe(p);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid  != 0) {
        // Parent: Output is to child via pipe[1]

        // Change stdout to pipe[1]
        dup2(p[1], 1);
        close(p[0]);

        r = execvp("ls", ls_args);
    } else {
        //Child: Input is from pipe[0] and output is via stdout.
        dup2(p[0], 0);
        close(p[1]);

        r = execvp("grep", grep_args);
        close(p[0]);
    }

    return r;
}
```

For `a | b | c`, the hint is to use two pipes, i.e., `p1[2]` and `p2[2]`.