# implement the char ' | ' to get a pipe between two processes in C

Tags: c, system-calls

I have to implement the pipe char ' | ' in my own mini shell in C (Linux).
for exemple.... after compiling file.c and then ./a.out I should be able to digit ls | sort, and the program should be able to work as the main shell. 
How can I do such a thing? thanks

Comment: Do you want to use pipe's with C code? There are some posix functions to do them

Comment: My shell should be able to see the char ' | ' in the same way the unix shell see it..I don't know if I explained correctly

Comment: Related also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8389033/694576

Comment: Please in the future do some research before asking.

Comment: the code in this link gives me an error in cmdLine. "error: unknown type name ‘cmdLine’
 void runPipedCommands(cmdLine* command, char* userInput) {"