# Multiple pipes in C output error

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm learning C and currently i'm trying to make a shell. Anyway i made a test program to figure out how multiple pipes work. I changed the program to use a single pipe command and it prints the result fine. Then i changed it back to this code where that runs it for 2 pipes, but i always get output 0. I really have no clue why the output is 0. Can you help me?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int j;
    pid_t pid;
    int pfd[4];
    char * ls[] = {"ls","-l",0};
    char * sort[] = {"sort","-u",0};
    char * wc[] = {"wc","-l",0};
    int fd = open("outputfolder.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        if ( pipe(pfd + i*2) < 0 )
        {
            perror("pipe\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 2; i ++ )
    {
        if ( i == 2 )
        {
            pid = fork();
            if ( pid == 0 )
            {
                if ( dup2(pfd[(i-1)*2],0) < 0 )
                {
                    perror("dup2\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if ( dup2(fd,1) < 0 )
                {
                    perror("dup2\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
                {
                    close(pfd[j]);
                }
                if  ( execvp(wc[0],wc) < 0 )
                {
                    perror("execvpwc\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
            else if ( pid == -1 )
            {
                perror("fork\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if ( i != 2 )
        {
            pid = fork();
            if ( pid == 0 )
            {
                if ( i != 0 )
                {
                    if ( dup2(pfd[(i-1)*2],0) < 0 )
                    {
                        perror("dup2\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }

                if ( dup2(pfd[i*2+1],1) < 0 )
                {
                    perror("dup2\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
                {
                    close(pfd[j]);
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if ( execvp(ls[0],ls) < 0 )
                    {
                        perror("execvpls\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
                else if ( i == 1 )
                {
                    if ( execvp(sort[0],sort) < 0 )
                    {
                        perror("execvpsort\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if ( pid == -1 )
            {
                perror("fork\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
    {
        close(pfd[j]);
    }

    while(waitpid(0,0,0)>=0);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The number that it should print should be 19 for my directory

Comment: At the very least, you have undefined behavior in this line: `if ( pipe(pfd + i*2) < 0 )`. `i` can be as big as 3, which means `pfd + 6` will be passed as an argument to `pipe`, which will try to write there something.

Comment: I got this line of code from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389033/implementation-of-multiple-pipes-in-c?rq=1  in which the best answer opens the pipes the same way

Comment: Nevermind you were right. I counted twice the number of pipes. Thank you for making me see the error

Comment: You're also opening 4 pipes where only two are needed.  I suggest deleting this question.  (Your exemplar uses the correct loop: `for(i = 0; i < (numPipes); i += 2)
        pipe(pipefds + i);` — incrementing by 2, not 1.)