# Trying to execute piped commands that are taken from a readline function

Tags: c, shell, pipe, readline

I am doing a project for my school in C, which consists of building a minishell, a small version of Shell. I already have done all the parsing and can execute single commands. However, when I try to work with pipes, I get all sorts of different behavior. I need to use the readline function to get input, and I can't make it work with pipes for my life. I made a small code just to try to fix the behavior of pipes and readline:

```
void    ft_execvp(char **args)
{
    execvp(args[0], args);
}

void    ft_pipes_executer(char *cmd, int index, int last)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     pipefd[2];

    // SPLIT CMD
    char **args = ft_split(cmd, ' ');

    // CREATE PIPE
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
        exit (1);

    // CREATE FORK
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        exit (1);

    // CHILD PROCESS
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        else if (index == last)
            close(pipefd[0]);
        else
        {
            close(pipefd[0]);
            dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        ft_execvp(args);
    }

    // PARENT PROCESS
    else
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            close(pipefd[1]);
            dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        }
        else if (index == last)
            ;
        else
        {
            close(pipefd[1]);
            dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        }
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }
}

char    **ft_command_creator(char *input)
{
    int i = 0;
    int n_pipes = 0;
    while (input[i])
    {
        if (input[i] == '|')
            n_pipes++;
        i++;
    }
    char **commands = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (n_pipes + 1));
    if (!commands)
        exit (1);
    i = 0;
    char *tmp = input;
    while (i < n_pipes + 1)
    {
        if (ft_strchr(tmp, '|') != NULL)
        {
            commands[i] = ft_substr(tmp, 0, strchr(tmp, '|') - tmp);
            if (!commands[i])
                exit (1);
            tmp = strchr(tmp, '|') + 2;
        }
        else if (strchr(tmp, '|') == NULL)
        {
            commands[i] = strdup(tmp);
            if (!commands[i])
                exit (1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    int last_cmd_len = strlen(commands[n_pipes]);
    if (last_cmd_len > 0 && commands[n_pipes][last_cmd_len - 1] == '\n')
        commands[n_pipes][last_cmd_len - 1] = '\0';
    commands[i] = NULL;
    return (commands);
}

void    ft_free(char *input, char **cmds)
{
    free(input);
    int i = 0;
    while (cmds[i])
    {
        free(cmds[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(cmds);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *input;
    char **cmds;

    input = NULL;
    cmds = NULL;
    while (1)
    {
        input = readline("ms> ");
        printf("input: %s\n", input);
        if (!input)
            exit (1);
        add_history(input);
        cmds = ft_command_creator(input);
        int last = 0;
        while (cmds[last])
            last++;
        for (int i = 0; cmds[i]; i++)
        {
            ft_pipes_executer(cmds[i], i, last);
        }
    }
    ft_free(input, cmds);
    rl_clear_history();
}
```

I know it is a bad code with some memory leaks, but this is just to try and understand the behaviour of pipes and readline. What happens is that when I pass a command like ls | grep a, it takes the 'answer' as input and makes it into a command. Does anybody know how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: For a simple example, with `command1 | command2` you have one pipeline, with two commands, and that requires a *third* entry in the `commands` array for the null-pointer terminator. Are you sure you allocate enough elements for the `commands` array?

Comment: And more generally, please use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code, line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Also more generally: Don't write too much code at once. It just makes it harder to test and debug. Start with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors. Once it builds cleanly test it in any way you can imagine. Once it passes all tests, then add a ***small*** piece of code. Build and test as before. And so on. If there's a problem, it's much easier to isolate that parts into a [mre], and debug to make sure it works.

Comment: There are several _weaknesses_ in `ft_command_creator()` that will likely prevent any pipelining from functioning... If you want to figure out pipes, you should get rid of the buggy "parsing" and work with a _hard wired_ array of strings that are command names. Eg: `char *arr[] = { "ls -l", "grep fileX", NULL }` A lot less code to try to understand.

Comment: `readline` means _editing_, i.e. going back into the read buffer and changing what is there. I don't understand the purpose of this in the connection of pipes - it simply does not make sense to me. At the very least, you would need to define exactly what effect you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks everyone for trying to help. if anybody has the same question, here is the solution I found: in my minishell project, not in this test, I ended up allocating memory for all pipes, and opening them at once. The biggest problem, though, was with how I was closing my pipes in the wrong way. When I closed all of them both in the child process and in the parent process, my program began executing the commands the right way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389033/implementation-of-multiple-pipes-in-c this question was the one that helped me the most.