# Fork-exec pipe redirection issue

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, pipe

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

In summary, it creates input and output pipes and fork-exec's the `sort` program. The parent reads the dictionary `/usr/share/dict/words` and writes it to the pipe that is `dup2()`'d to `sort`'s standard in and, likewise, reads the output from it, printing it to the terminal (the standard output of the parent). Or, at least, that's what's supposed to be happening.

A backtrace says that the parent hangs at the `read()` on line 130 (marked with the comment 'XXX'). It's almost as though `sort` isn't aware of the end-of-file, but closing the write end of `pipeIn` should 'signal' this, right?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int pipeIn[2];
    int pipeOut[2];

    if ((pipe(pipeIn)) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((pipe(pipeOut)) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t child = fork();

    if (child == 0)
    {
        // This is child!

        if ((dup2(pipeIn[0], STDIN_FILENO)) == -1)
        {
            perror("dup2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((dup2(pipeOut[1], STDOUT_FILENO)) == -1)
        {
            perror("dup2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((dup2(pipeOut[1], STDERR_FILENO)) == -1)
        {
            perror("dup2");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(pipeIn[0])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(pipeOut[1])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((execlp("sort", "-r", NULL)) == -1)
        {
            perror("execlp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else if (child == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is parent!

        if ((close(pipeIn[0])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(pipeOut[1])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int dict = open("/usr/share/dict/words", O_RDONLY);

        if (dict == -1)
        {
            perror("open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char buf[1024];
        int count;

        while ((count = read(dict, buf, sizeof(char) * 1024)) > 0)
        {
            putchar('.');

            if ((write(pipeIn[1], buf, count)) == -1)
            {
                perror("write 1");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (count == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(dict)) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(pipeIn[1])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while ((count = read(pipeOut[0], buf, sizeof(char) * 1024)) > 0) // XXX
        {
            putchar('!');

            if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, count)) == -1)
            {
                perror("write 2");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        if (count == -1)
        {
            perror("read");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ((close(pipeOut[0])) == -1)
        {
            perror("close");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you for any input (pardon the pun).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble with fork(), pipe(), dup2() and exec() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916900/having-trouble-with-fork-pipe-dup2-and-exec-in-c)

Comment: I've already read that and it seems rather different.

Comment: I agree - the cross-referenced question is somewhat different.

Comment: You normally would not send `sort`'s standard error down the pipe; you'd leave it going to the same place as the standard error of the invoking process (which is likely the terminal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not closing the unused ends of your pipe in the chile process. So you need to add the following code somewhere before the `exec`

```
    if ((close(pipeIn[1])) == -1)
    {
        perror("close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((close(pipeOut[0])) == -1)
    {
        perror("close");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: +1 - You're right.  It is counter-intuitive, but  if you are using a pipe as standard input or standard output in a child process, then you normally end up closing **both** of the file descriptors returned by `pipe()`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get it at first, but kind of makes sense now that I've thought about it (which I never have until today). After the fork there are effectively two open file descriptiors which can write to the pipe. So you cannot get an `eof` on reading from the pipe until ALL the file descriptors for the writing end have been closed.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but it's not printing the list of words in reverse order. Is the syntax of `execlp("sort", "-r", NULL);` wrong?

Comment: Oh, it needs to be `execlp("sort", "sort", "-r", NULL);` - I don't know why though!

Comment: @bean Because `argv[0]` is always the name of the process. Lets you control how it shows up in `ps` and other process information.